# Which escaping function should be use on register_post_type label?

Tags: custom-post-types, translation

If I register a post type then which escaping should I use for escaping label?

```
function book_setup_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'public'    => true,
        'label'     => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'book_setup_post_type' );
```

Comment: For securing output you should just do alright with esc_html() and if it's gonna be translation ready you would be better off using esc_html_e() or esc_html__().

For your ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. Escaping should happen late, on output. This is just registering the strings for later use, so it's too early to escape. All the places in WordPress where the post type label is used automatically, WordPress should already be escaping it.

If you're outputting any of the labels yourself, you would probably use `esc_html()`:

```
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'book' );
$post_type_labels = get_post_type_labels( $post_type_object );

echo esc_html( $post_type_labels->singular_name );
```